# Cant figure where to place a wait in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, wait

Im trying to make a shooting script for the player and have it reload every time ammo is less than 1, I need to have a wait whenever it does then let the player shoot again but I don't know how. I tried having the variable reload = 1 every time ammo is less than 1, and then have reload change back to 0 after a certain amount of seconds. I know how to make it so you cant shoot if reload is equal to 1 but i cant figure out how to add the wait.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qjNyXxTrj8/

Comment: Do not use external sites to post code, just include it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably best if you re-write the code using a Coroutine,

```
void Start()
{
  StartCoroutine(ShootRoutine);
}

IEnumerator ShootRoutine()
{
 while (true) // newer exit this loop
 {
   if (!Input.GetButton ("Fire1")) yield return null; //not shooting, do nothing
   else
   {
    if (ammo>0)
    { 
       Shoot(); // move your ammo decrease here
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayBetweenShots); // cooldown after shot
    }
    if (ammo<=0)
    {
       DisableEffects();
       Reload();
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime);
       EnableEffects();
    }
   }
  } // while(true) loops back here
}
```

also, there is no need for timer+=Time.deltaTime - this value is always available as Time.time

Answer (score 0):

In your reload method, you can start a coroutine that waits a number of seconds before turning `reload` variable back to original value.

```
private IEnumerator WaitForFewSeconds()
{
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
  reload = 0;
}

void Reload()
{
  // do your thing
  StartCoroutine(WaitForFewSeconds());
}
```

Comment: Except nothing stops `Reload()` from being called every frame for 2 seconds. Meaning if you use up all your ammo in less than 2 seconds you'll get an instant reload!